# Sending data from another system to update HubSpot live chat properties

Tags: javascript, hubspot

I'm using hubspot's live chat feature in one of my products. Currently, I am using a chatbot conversation to get user information in order to identify a user. But I need a way to get the user's input (email, username), whenever they start a conversation through the chat widget without asking them.

Is there any possible way to send data from another system to update the HubSpot live chat?

Comment: The question is unclear.  HubSpot has a [Visitor Identification](https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/api/conversation/visitor-identification) end-point.

Comment: @Yogi thank you for the reference. I am currently using hubspot's live chat feature in a UEM product. So whenever a user starts a conversation through the live chat, I need to send their logged-in email and username to store in hubspot as properties. I there I am not supposed to ask them email or username.